# spotify search API query

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

[image]

how can i get the followers count and genre and other results from the code down below:

```
q="A"
sp.search(q,limit=1,offset=0,type="artist",market="US")
followers=result['artists']['items']
pprint(followers)

[{'external_urls': {'spotify': 
'https://open.spotify.com/artist/0ZXKT0FCsLWkSLCjoBJgBX'},
'followers': {'href': None, 'total': 121213},
'genres': ['gothic metal', 'progressive metal'],
'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0ZXKT0FCsLWkSLCjoBJgBX',
'id': '0ZXKT0FCsLWkSLCjoBJgBX',
'images': [{'height': 640,
          'url': 
'https://i.scdn.co/image/350538b94d7d1829d983eaf4ee4aeca2af071f2c',
          'width': 640},
         {'height': 320,
          'url': 
'https://i.scdn.co/image/1a00c2a831a77f681516d3be11f2f0c6a9bb85b2',
          'width': 320},
         {'height': 160,
          'url': 
'https://i.scdn.co/image/8066cb28d68d3ce4924f33e6eca1b3a2a391eca6',
          'width': 160}],
'name': 'Anathema',
'popularity': 53,
'type': 'artist',
'uri': 'spotify:artist:0ZXKT0FCsLWkSLCjoBJgBX'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I would recommend brushing up on your data structures in Python by visiting this link: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html
But to more directly answer your question, it would appear that the "followers" list you've defined here is a list of dictionary items. In your case, the list is only of length 1, so you could access the contents within it as follows:

```
contents = followers[0]
```

(NOTE: this would only return the first dictionary item in the list if the list had a length greater than 1. You would need to iterate through the list to find all elements if the length was larger than 1.)
This would return the dictionary item associated with the first, and only, element of followers. From there, you could access specific parts of the dictionary by doing:

```
contents['genre']
```

or

```
contents['followers']
```

(or similar calls for the other data fields in the dictionary)
Now with the first one, referencing the "genre" types, you will get a list back. This list contains all of the different genres to which this particular artist belongs. In this case, Anathema (the name of the band returned) belongs to both gothic metal and progressive metal. Thus, the list returned by accessing contents['genre'] will contain only these two elements.
Additionally, the contents['followers'] will return another dictionary: this one including information pertaining to the followers of the band Anathema. To access the follower count, you could do the following:

```
follow_count = contents['followers']['total']
```

This should provide you with the results you're looking for.